# Unable to execute PowerShell in Lambda when passing Invoke Command

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-lambda, aws-ssm

I am looking to execute a PowerShell script through AWS Lambda.

When I execute the script without the invoke-command it executes. When I use the invoke-command the script fails. The lambda is running inside the VPC. I have assigned elastic IP to the lambda interface. Here is my script:

```
#Requires -Modules @{ModuleName='PSWSMan';ModuleVersion='2.0.0'}
  #Requires -Modules @{ModuleName='AWS.Tools.EC2';ModuleVersion='4.1.15.0'}
  #Requires -Modules @{ModuleName='AWS.Tools.Common';ModuleVersion='4.1.15.0'}


  $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "XXXXX" -AsPlainText -Force

  $myCreds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 
  "XXX@YYYY.com", $secpasswd


  Get-EC2NetworkInterface -Filter @(@{name ='description'; values='Created By Amazon 
  Workspaces for AWS Account ID XXXXXXX'}) | Select-Object -Property PrivateIpAddress | 
  ForEach-Object -Process {
  (Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.PrivateIpAddress -Credential 
  $myCreds -ScriptBlock {
  ($code = "XXXXXXX");
  ($id = "XXXXXXX");
  ($region = "eu-west-1"); 
  ($dir = "C:\TEMP\ssm");
  (New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $dir -Force);(cd $dir);(New-Object 
  System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("https://amazon-ssm-eu-west-1.s3.eu-west- 
  1.amazonaws.com/latest/windows_amd64/AmazonSSMAgentSetup.exe", $dir + 
  "\AmazonSSMAgentSetup.exe");
  (Start-Process .\AmazonSSMAgentSetup.exe -ArgumentList @("/q", 
  "/log", "install.log", "CODE=$code", "ID=$id", "REGION=$region") -Wait)})}
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
[Error] - Could not find a part of the path '/var/runtime/ref'.
  An exception was thrown when the constructor for type 'Demo.Bootstrap' was invoked. Check 
 inner exception for more details.: LambdaException


   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean 
   wrapExceptions, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& 
   hasNoDefaultCtor)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtorSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean 
   wrapExceptions, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean 
   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   Could not find a part of the path '/var/runtime/ref'.: DirectoryNotFoundException
   at Amazon.Lambda.PowerShellHost.PowerShellFunctionHost..ctor()
   at Amazon.Lambda.PowerShellHost.PowerShellFunctionHost..ctor(String 
   powerShellScriptFileName)
   at Demo.Bootstrap..ctor() in **C:\Users\himan\AppData\Local\Temp\Demo\Bootstrap.cs**:line
```

This is a directory on my laptop. Unable to understand why this is showing in the lambda console.

```
C:\Users\himan\AppData\Local\Temp\Demo\Bootstrap.cs
```

Using this command to publish Lambda:

```
Publish-AWSPowerShellLambda -ScriptPath .\Demo.ps1 -Name  Demo -Region eu-west-1
```

Thanks
Himanshu

Comment: Use either
Select-Object -Property PrivateIpAddress | ForEach-Object -Process { Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_
OR
Get-EC2NetworkInterface -Filter ...  |
  ForEach-Object -Process {
  (Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.PrivateIpAddress
But the Select-Object return the PrivateAddress value, that is stored in the $_ variable. The $_ is no more the EC2NetworkInterface object. So $_.PrivateAddress is null and you end to your local computer.

Comment: Tried both Select-Object -Property PrivateIpAddress | ForEach-Object -Process { Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ OR Get-EC2NetworkInterface -Filter ... | ForEach-Object -Process { (Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.PrivateIpAddress. Getting the same error as before.